# Update json array in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a data field that looks like this :

```
{ "field1" : [{"name":'name1',"value1":true},
              {"name":'name2',"value2":false}
             ],
  "field2" : [{"name":'name1',"value1":true},
              {"name":'name2',"value2":false}
            ]
}
```

Is it possible to update a specific field with an update ?

```
create table t_json (
   t_data json
);


insert into t_json values('{"field1":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}],"field1":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}]}');

select t_data->'field1' 
from t_json;
```

I tried this :

```
update t_json
set t_data->'a' = '[{"value1" : true, "value2" : false}]';
```

But I get an error : "syntax error at or near `->`

What is missing ?

Comment: `jsonb_set()`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: I tried update t_json
set t_data = jsonb_set(t_data,'{0,"field1"}','[{"name" : "works"}]');

but it looks like there is no effect ? I'd like to update the whole field

Comment: You need to ditch the `0` as you are not updating the first element of a list, so use only `{field1}` and it should work. Also, edit your question so your datatype is `jsonb` in table creation.

Comment: Again, you made a typo in your example, as you inserted `field1` twice. You should probably replace the second one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wanted to post this here in case it helps anybody else. By all means use JSON over JSONB unless you actually need features that JSONB affords you. In general, if you need to perform queries on the JSON data itself, use JSONB. If you are just needing to store data, use JSON.

Anyhow, here is how I am updating a `JSON[]` field:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = ARRAY[$${"hello": "world"}$$, $${"baz": "bing"}$$]::JSON[]
```

The important things to notice are this:

- The array is wrapped like this: `ARRAY[ ... ]::JSON[]`
- Each item in the array is wrapped like this: `$${ "foo": "bar" }$$`

It is worth noting that this same technique can be used for other array types. For example, if you have a `text[]` column, the query would look like this:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = ARRAY[$$hello world$$, $$baz bing$$]::TEXT[]`
```

Answer (score 4):

## Fixing your typos

Doubt it. This is not valid json. `name1` and `name2` must be double quoted. To ease working with json, **ALWAYS** use double quotes. **ALWAYS** query-quote with double-dollar.

```
{ "field1" : [{"name":'name1',"value1":true},
              {"name":'name2',"value2":false}
             ],
  "field2" : [{"name":'name1',"value1":true},
              {"name":'name2',"value2":false}
            ]
}
```

And, what you `INSERTED` is also funky.. [**ALWAYS** paste beautified valid JSON in your question.](http://jsonformatter.org/)

```
{
  "field1":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}],
  "field1":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}]
}
```

Let's change that and fix it.

```
{
  "field1":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}],
  "field2":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}]
}
```

Now let's put it in a query..

```
TRUNCATE t_json;
INSERT INTO t_json (t_data) VALUES ($$
  {
    "field1":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}],
    "field2":[{"name":"name1","value" : true},{"name":"name2","value" : false}]
  }
$$);
```

## Making the update of the JSON

Now it works.. Now you can update it as you want..

```
UPDATE t_json
SET t_data = jsonb_set(
  t_data::jsonb,
  '{field1}',
  $${"whatever":1}$$
);
```

## Change from JSON to JSONB

Notice we're having to cast to `jsonb`. As a general rule, **NEVER** use JSON (not everyone agrees, see comments). There is no point. Instead use the newer JSONB.

```
ALTER TABLE t_json ALTER COLUMN t_data TYPE jsonb ;
```

Now you can do

```
UPDATE t_json
SET t_data = jsonb_set(
  t_data,
  '{field1}',
  $${"whatever":1}$$
);
```

Comment: "*NEVER use JSON*" - well that depends on what you want to do. JSONB takes up more space. JSON is also a bit faster for inserts and (complete) updates.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name JSONB can be faster for updates too. Depends on if you have to re-validate or not, right? JSONB-JSONB doesn't require re-validation. And, size assumes something of the white space of the original json? It's not hard to imagine the whitespace taking more space than the binary format. In the above example, fully beautified json takes 268bytes. Converting to JSONB shrinks it to 202bytes. That's not to say JSON can't be smaller than the binary representation, but that's an edge case to be concerned with it. It's slower to query.

Comment: As a general rule for a new comer. I think the validated-text types are better off ignored entirely when there is a binary representation.

Comment: The JSON in the example takes 170 byte, JSONB 202 byte: http://rextester.com/DOHMP38401   See also here: http://www.glassgraden.com/news/JSON-and-PostgreSQL:-A-Powerful-Combination/

Comment: @Evan Carroll Your query worked but it removed the array from field1 and rather resulted as a simple json object in it and the output was "field1": {"whatever": "1"}, so, what worked in my case was UPDATE t_json
SET t_data = jsonb_set(
  t_data,
  '{field1}',
  '[{"whatever":1}]'
);