# Update Json object in an array of json in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
+---+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id | Name | Mobile |                               jsonb_column                                   |
+---+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | Name1|   123  |  [{"2023-03-01": "false"}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}] |
| 2 | Name2|   234  |  [{"2023-03-10": "false"}, {"2023-03-13": "false"}, {"2023-03-15": "false"}] |
| 3 | Name3|   456  |  [{"2023-03-01": "false"}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}] |
+---+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I was trying to update the json value using an sql statement where a particular mobile is present.

**Expected Output**

```
+---+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id | Name | Mobile |                               jsonb_column                                   |
+---+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | Name1|   123  |  [{"2023-03-01": "true"}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}] |
| 2 | Name2|   234  |  [{"2023-03-10": "false"}, {"2023-03-13": "false"}, {"2023-03-15": "false"}] |
| 3 | Name3|   456  |  [{"2023-03-01": "false"}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}] |
+---+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**I Tried**

```
UPDATE table SET jsonb_column = jsonb_set(json_column::jsonb, '{2023-03-01}',  CASE WHEN jsonb_column->>'2023-03-01' = 'false' THEN 'true'::jsonb ELSE 'false'::jsonb END) where mobile = '123';
```

But that is throwing me an error like:

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: path element at position 1 is not an integer: "2023-03-01"
```

I saw multiple stackoverflow answers but can not figure out how to write the query.

1. [Update field in array of objects in json postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840574/update-field-in-array-of-objects-in-json-postgres)
2. [Postgres: update specific json object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032785/postgres-update-specific-json-object-in-array)
3. [Update json array in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593815/update-json-array-in-postgres)

How do I write the query to update the value inside the array of json?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to update jsons regularly, you should urgently thing about normalising you data, and get rid of the json

```
CREATE TABLE testdata
    ("id" int, "Name" varchar(5), "Mobile" int, "jsonb_column" jsonb)
;
    
INSERT INTO testdata
    ("id", "Name", "Mobile", "jsonb_column")
VALUES
    (1, 'Name1', 123, '[{"2023-03-01": "false"}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}]'),
    (2, 'Name2', 234, '[{"2023-03-10": "false"}, {"2023-03-13": "false"}, {"2023-03-15": "false"}]'),
    (3, 'Name3', 456, '[{"2023-03-01": "false"}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}]')
;
```

```
WITH CTE AS
  (
SELECT "id", "Name", "Mobile",
  CASE WHEN (value->>'2023-03-01') ::BOOLEAN  = false  THEN
  jsonb_set(value,'{"2023-03-01"}','true'::jsonb,false)
  ELSE jsonb_set(value,'{"2023-03-01"}','false'::jsonb,false) END value
  FROM testdata
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements("jsonb_column")
  WHERE "Mobile" = 123),
  CTE2 as (
SELECT "id", "Name", "Mobile",jsonb_agg(value) as  "jsonb_column"
FROM CTE
GROUP BY "id", "Name", "Mobile")
UPDATE testdata
SET "jsonb_column" = CTE2."jsonb_column"
FROM CTE2
WHERE testdata.id = cte2.id
```

> ```
> UPDATE 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM testdata
```

| id | Name | Mobile | jsonb_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Name2 | 234 | [{"2023-03-10": "false"}, {"2023-03-13": "false"}, {"2023-03-15": "false"}] |
| 3 | Name3 | 456 | [{"2023-03-01": "false"}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}] |
| 1 | Name1 | 123 | [{"2023-03-01": true}, {"2023-03-03": "false"}, {"2023-03-05": "false"}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FRWrOwnF)